# How to get purely unique number in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I must create unique keys for certain objects I create (needed for React key prop), where key can be any random string or number, but has to be truly unique for each time it's generated in program lifetime.

I tried to use `new Date().getTime()` as key, but encountered problem where multiple objects got assigned the same key when creating them in loop.

Is there a function which returns something purely unique each call as long as the program is running, or do I have to implement my own counter?

Comment: If it only needs to be unique for "as long as the program is running" then just implementing a counter would be a lot simpler and perform better than generating GUIDs. `var nextKey = (function() { var i=0; return function() { return i++; } })();` (You'd then just call `nextKey()` when you need an id.)

Comment: I am extending your approach! You can try this.
    `function getUUID(){
        var n = new Date().getTime();
        var m = new Date();
        var o = m.getMilliseconds();
        var uuid = n * o;
        return uuid;
    }`

Comment: @MavenMaverick - That doesn't work for the same reason the OP's code doesn't work: if you call the function multiple times within the same millisecond you get the same result.

Comment: How about using EPOCH `Date.now().toString(16)` it will be random and incrementing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a UUID:

```
function guid() {
  function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
      .toString(16)
      .substring(1);
  }
  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
    s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}
```

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/105074/5109911

alternative:
https://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/2MVFd/